# Eliminar y Editar datos de una base de datos sqlite con variable "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy tratando de realizar dos métodos uno para eliminar y otro para editar datos de una base de datos sqlite la cual se encarga de alimentar un ListView, cuando utilizo una variable normal de la base de datos para realizar estos procedimientos todo funciona bien pero cuando utilizo la variable con "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" la cual es la que necesito utilizar me saca de la aplicación.

alguien me puede ayudar con este problema

gracias

base de datos

```
  public static final String TABLA_ASIGNATURAS="asignaturas";
    public static final String ID_ASIGNATURA="id_asignatura";
    public static final String CAMPO_NOMBRE_ASIGNATURA="nombre_asignatura";

    public static final String CREAR_TABLA_ASIGNATURAS="CREATE TABLE " +""
            +TABLA_ASIGNATURAS+" ("+ID_ASIGNATURA+ "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+CAMPO_NOMBRE_ASIGNATURA+ " TEXT)";
```

Adapter ListView

```
public class AdapterLista extends BaseAdapter {

    Context contexto;
    ArrayList<String> lista;
    private PopupMenu popup;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public AdapterLista(Context contexto, ArrayList<String> lista,OnListItemClickListener listener) {
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.lista = lista;
        this.listener = listener;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)contexto.getSystemService(contexto.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public interface OnListItemClickListener {
        void delete(String item);
        void edit(String item);
    }

    private OnListItemClickListener listener;



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     final View vista= inflater.inflate(R.layout.elementolista,null);

        final TextView asignatura = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.textasignatura);
        ImageView opciones = (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.opciones);
        asignatura.setText(lista.get(position));

        opciones.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                popup = new PopupMenu(contexto, v);
                MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menulist, popup.getMenu());
                popup.show();
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {

                            case R.id.Editar:
                                listener.edit(String.valueOf(position));
                                break;

                            case R.id.Eliminar:
                                listener.delete(String.valueOf(position));
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        return vista;
    }
```

Eventos de editar y eliminar

```
 public void delete(String item){
            SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getWritableDatabase();
            String[] parametros={item};
            db.delete(tablas.TABLA_ASIGNATURAS,tablas.ID_ASIGNATURA+"=?",parametros);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Ya se elimino el usuario",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            ConsultarListaPersonas();

            db.close();
    }

 public void edit(String item){

             SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getWritableDatabase();
            String[] parametros={item};
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(tablas.CAMPO_NOMBRE_ASIGNATURA,asignatura.getText().toString());
            db.update(tablas.TABLA_ASIGNATURAS,values,tablas.ID_ASIGNATURA+"=?",parametros);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Ya se edito el usuario",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba a cambiar

```
public static final String CREAR_TABLA_ASIGNATURAS="CREATE TABLE " +""
            +TABLA_ASIGNATURAS+" ("+ID_ASIGNATURA+ "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+CAMPO_NOMBRE_ASIGNATURA+ " TEXT)";
```

Por

```
public static final String CREAR_TABLA_ASIGNATURAS="CREATE TABLE " +""
                +TABLA_ASIGNATURAS+" ("+ID_ASIGNATURA+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+CAMPO_NOMBRE_ASIGNATURA+ " TEXT)";
```

Parece que falta darle un espacio a " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" 
Espero que te ayude. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Debes corregir el query con el cual realizas la creaciòn de la tabla:

```
public static final String CREAR_TABLA_ASIGNATURAS="CREATE TABLE "+TABLA_ASIGNATURAS+" ("+ID_ASIGNATURA+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+CAMPO_NOMBRE_ASIGNATURA+ " TEXT)";
```

Despues de estos cambios **es importante eliminar la cachè de la app o eliminarla completamente y volver a subirla.**